# bash trap in background functions

Tags: bash, temporary-files, pid, exit

Calling a function in a script in background - using '&', the function is called in a `subshell`. When the function ends, the `subshell` ends, with an exit status. I would like to trap the exit signal of such `subshell` to automatically cancel log files. My testing script is as follow:

```
$ cat mscript.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env sh

mout="log.out"
rm -f $mout

# My testing log files
tmps=(first.tmp second.tmp third.tmp)

# Traps exit signal to delete the logfile upon exiting.
mtrap_tmp() {
  local ftmp="$1"
  # I create the tep file here:
  echo "init $ftmp" &>> $ftmp
  echo -e "\n($BASHPID) trapping \"$ftmp\"..." &>> $mout
  ## Here I trap the signal, to delete the temporary file.
  trap "rm -f \"$ftmp\"" EXIT
  echo -e "  trapped tmp file \"$ftmp\" to rm" &>> $mout
  echo "  $(ls -l $ftmp)" &>> $mout
}

# I trap the first and second log files within the script's pid. 
# Then I trap the third file in a subshell:
mtrap_tmp ${tmps[0]}
mtrap_tmp ${tmps[1]}
mtrap_tmp ${tmps[2]} &
wait $!

# Here I want to check the temp files do exist. 
# I expect the third file to be trapped in a subshell, 
# and hence to be non-existent once the subshell ends, 
# which should have happened after the `wait $!`:

for i in ${tmps[@]}; do
  echo -e "\nfinal check $i:" &>> $mout
  ls -l ${i} &>> $mout
done

echo "done"
exit 0
```

The output is as follow:

```
$  cat log.out 

(10598) trapping "first.tmp"...
  trapped tmp file "first.tmp" to rm
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 anadin ctgb 15 Jul  4 15:54 first.tmp

(10598) trapping "second.tmp"...
  trapped tmp file "second.tmp" to rm
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 anadin ctgb 16 Jul  4  2017 second.tmp

(10602) trapping "third.tmp"...
  trapped tmp file "third.tmp" to rm
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 anadin ctgb 15 Jul  4  2017 third.tmp

final check first.tmp:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anadin ctgb 15 Jul  4 15:54 first.tmp

final check second.tmp:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anadin ctgb 16 Jul  4 15:54 second.tmp

final check third.tmp:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anadin ctgb 15 Jul  4 15:54 third.tmp
```

I expected the file `third.tmp` to be deleted before the end of the script.
The strange thing is, only the second.tmp file has been cancelled:

```
$ ls *.tmp
first.tmp  third.tmp
```

I expect the third file only to be removed after the function exits. 
I expect the two other files to be removed after completion of the script.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Since the third trap is created in a subshell it is also activated/run when *that* shell exits, attempting to remove the third file before it's been created. Therefore the third file exists after the script is done.

Every time you `trap […] SIGNAL` you *overwrite* the trap for that signal, so only the second trap survives in the top shell. Therefore the first file exists after the script is done.

An `echo` in the trap or possibly `set -o xtrace` would show you better what's going on. You can also run `trap` on its own to see which traps are in effect.